# INSERT SELECT INTO TABLE with additional variables

Tags: php, t-sql, sql-insert, insert-select

columnI do an insert like this:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO EHS.dbo.T_Kunden_ApArchiv ([KuNr] ,[KontaktName] ,[KontaktVorname] ,[KontaktpersonPosition] ,[Anrede] ,[Abteilung] ,[OrtsName] ,[KStraße] ,[KPlz] ,[KTel] ,[KFax] ,[KHandy] ,[Ke-mail] ,[KInternet])
SELECT [KuNr] ,[KontaktName2] ,[KontaktVorname2] ,[KontaktpersonPosition2] ,[Anrede2] ,[Abteilung2] ,[OrtsName2] ,[KStraße2] ,[KPlz2] ,[KTel2] ,[KFax2] ,[KHandy2] ,[Ke-mail2] ,[KInternet2] FROM EHS.dbo.T_Kunden 
WHERE KuNr = '".$data['kundenNR']."'";

// execute
odbc_exec($db1_link, $sql);
```

everything is fine with it but I have to put in the php-variable `$vertriebNr` additionally into the column `ArchiviertDurch`

How can I do this without an extra update?

Comment: Please show us your PHP code?

Comment: that be column ArchiviertDurch , not row, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO EHS.dbo.T_Kunden_ApArchiv ([KuNr] ,[KontaktName] ,[KontaktVorname] ,
            [KontaktpersonPosition] ,[Anrede] ,[Abteilung] ,[OrtsName] ,[KStraße] ,
            [KPlz] ,[KTel] ,[KFax] ,[KHandy] ,[Ke-mail] ,[KInternet], 
            [ArchiviertDurch])
        SELECT [KuNr] ,[KontaktName2] ,[KontaktVorname2] ,[KontaktpersonPosition2] ,
               [Anrede2] ,[Abteilung2] ,[OrtsName2] ,[KStraße2] ,[KPlz2] ,[KTel2] ,
               [KFax2] ,[KHandy2] ,[Ke-mail2] ,[KInternet2], " . $vertriebNr . "
        FROM EHS.dbo.T_Kunden 
        WHERE KuNr = '".$data['kundenNR']."'";

// execute
odbc_exec($db1_link, $sql);
```

I assumed `$vertriebNr` is an integer so i didn't add `'` chars around it in query.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is this:

```
> INSERT INTO EHS.dbo.T_Kunden_ApArchiv ([KuNr] ,[KontaktName]
> ,[KontaktVorname] ,[KontaktpersonPosition] ,[Anrede] ,[Abteilung]
> ,[OrtsName] ,[KStraße] ,[KPlz] ,[KTel] ,[KFax] ,[KHandy] ,[Ke-mail]
> ,[KInternet],[the column where you want ArchiviertDurch] ) 
>  VALUES( SELECT ([KuNr] ,[KontaktName2] ,[KontaktVorname2]
> ,[KontaktpersonPosition2] ,[Anrede2] ,[Abteilung2] ,[OrtsName2]
> ,[KStraße2] ,[KPlz2] ,[KTel2] ,[KFax2] ,[KHandy2] ,[Ke-mail2]
> ,[KInternet2] FROM EHS.dbo.T_Kunden WHERE KuNr = 'K000097'), [ArchiviertDurch] );
```